# SQL UPDATE to replace all text within brackets with empty string

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

In the query column below, I want to remove the brackets and the text inside them.

Sample data (id, query):

```
25, some data (example1) more text
28, text (example2)
```

converted to:

```
25, some data more text
28, text
```

I have tried the following SQL but the values aren't changed:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET query = REPLACE(query, '%(%)%', '')
WHERE query like '%(%)%';
```

Comment: `replace()` does not support wildcards. You want `regexp_replace()`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this using `regexp_replace()` as:

```
select regexp_replace('some data (example1) more text', '\(.*\)', '')
```

You would just put the expression in the `set` clause:

```
UPDATE mytable
     SET query = regexp_replace(query, '\(.*\)', '')
WHERE query like '%(%)%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
replace(regexp_replace('some data (example1) more text', '(?<=\()(.*?)(?=\))', ''), '()', '');
```

[demo](http://rextester.com/EAMQ31727)